# How do I compile an XS module from CPAN manually?

Tags: perl, cpan, xs

I just downloaded an XS module from CPAN, but want to compile it by hand, not using `cpan`. Running `perl Makefile.PL` and `make` creates `.c`, `.o`, `.xs` and `.bs` files, but I don't see any `.pm` to put in my path. What am I missing?

I don't want to `make install` it for every user.

Comment: Have you tried "make test" and "make install"? Which module is this? If you don't want to "make install" for every user then you can install into a global perl library location, or perhaps create a binary package. Which OS?

Comment: @ptomli: I just edited that I don't want to install it for every user because I want it to be simple to change. It's Math::FFTW.

Comment: @ptomli: Ubuntu. Normally to install something just for me, I'd put the .pm files in one of the paths that Perl looks for modules in, but which file should I put there in this case?

Comment: When you've done "make" you should find a "blib/lib/Math/FFTW.pm" in the build directory. You'll probably also need to XS binary.

Comment: @ptomli: Thanks. Now perl finds FFTW.pm (in `./Math`), but not the binary. I put FFTW.o both in `./` and `./Math`.

Comment: @ptomli Ah I see, it's the .so file from `blib/arch/auto/Math/FFTW/FFTW.so`. Thank you! You should write this up as an answer, so I can accept it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you run "make" you should discover the .pm file in the `blib/lib/Math` directory, and the .so in the `blib/arch/auto/Math/FFTW` directory.

Answer (score 7):

Use [INSTALL_BASE](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/ExtUtils::MakeMaker#INSTALL_BASE).